# Incorrect values inside goroutines when looping

Tags: go

I have read through [CommonMistakes](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CommonMistakes#using-goroutines-on-loop-iterator-variables) as well as run my code through the -race flag, but I can't seem to pinpoint what is wrong here:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    i := 1
    totalHashFields := 6
    for i <= totalHashFields {
        Combinations(totalHashFields, i, func(c []int) {
            fmt.Println("Outside goroutine:", c)
            go func(c []int) {
                fmt.Println("Inside goroutine:", c)
            }(c)
        })
        i++
    }
}

func Combinations(n, m int, emit func([]int)) {
    s := make([]int, m)
    last := m - 1
    var rc func(int, int)
    rc = func(i, next int) {
        for j := next; j < n; j++ {
            s[i] = j
            if i == last {
                emit(s)
            } else {
                rc(i+1, j+1)
            }
        }
        return
    }
    rc(0, 0)
}
```

(The Combinations function is a combinations [algo](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations) for those interested)

Here is some of the output from fmt.Println:

```
Outside goroutine: [0 1 4]
Inside goroutine: [5 5 5]
Outside goroutine: [0 1 2 3 4 5]
Inside goroutine: [5 5 5 5 5 5]
```

Basically, even though I'm passing c as a parameter to my anonymous go function, the value is consistently different to the value outside of this scope. In the output above, I expected the 2 "Inside" values to also be [0 1 4] and [0 1 2 3 4 5], respectfully.

Comment: You should post a working example. E.g. you did not show what `Combinations` does or how `data` is declared and used.

Comment: I have cleaned up the code to not include any non relevancy.

Comment: With my latest edit, you should be able to just copy/paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you goroutines all work on distinc int slices but these share a common backing array: After completing `Combinations` the slice `s` will be full of `5`s. Your `c` in main shares the underlying backing array with s.

But your goroutines do not start executing until `Combinations` is done so once they do start, the will see the final value of `s` which is just 5s.

Here it does not help to pass in the slice like you did as this makes a proper copy of `c` but not of the backing array.

Try

```
Combinations(totalHashFields, i, func(c []int) {
    fmt.Println("Outside goroutine:", c)
    cpy := make([]int, len(c))
    copy(cpy, c)
    go func(c []int) {
        fmt.Println("Inside goroutine:", c)
    }(cpy)
})
```

to make a "deep copy" of c.